# what the advantage of using zip function df['full_name']=zip(df['name'],df['last name'])

Tags: python, pandas, zip

i am trying to understand.

what the advantage of using zip function

```
df['full_name']=zip(df['name'],df['last name'])
```

instead of

```
df['full_name']=df['name']+ " " + df['last name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's not zip that matters.

> df['full_name']=zip(df['name'],df['last name'])

The element in the column `full_name` are tuples.

> df['full_name']=df['name']+ " " + df['last name']

If you write this, the element in the column `full_name` are strings.

Strings are better for showing and printing, but some information about its structure is lost.

For example, if name is `"A"` and last name is `"B C"`, if join them with a space, it will be `"A B C"`. It's OK for human, but for machines, it can not tell if it was `"A"` `"B C"` or `"A B"` `"C"`, as "structure info" is lost as I said.

So which one to choose depends on your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

For tuples by `name` and `last name` use first solution (converted to list for avoid zip objects):

```
df['full_name']= list(zip(df['name'],df['last name']))
```

For joined columns by space is used:

```
df['full_name']=df['name']+ " " + df['last name']
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['name1','name2'],
                   'last name':['last  name1','last name2']})

df['full_name0']= zip(df['name'],df['last name'])
df['full_name1']= list(zip(df['name'],df['last name']))
df['full_name2']=df['name']+ " " + df['last name']

print (df)
    name    last name                          full_name0  \
0  name1  last  name1  <zip object at 0x000000000F975DC0>   
1  name2   last name2  <zip object at 0x000000000F975DC0>   

             full_name1         full_name2  
0  (name1, last  name1)  name1 last  name1  
1   (name2, last name2)   name2 last name2  

print (type(df['full_name1'].iat[0]))
<class 'tuple'>

print (type(df['full_name2'].iat[0]))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: thanks, so  i can use df['full_name5']="'" + df['name']+"'" +"," +"'" + df['last name']+"'"   that give me the same.      in that case ' is there any advantage of using zip?

Comment: @rafine - Yes, if need output strings, without first and last `+`.

Comment: you both helpes me .  thanks a a lot. but the other answer explain me the advantage

Answer (score 0):

zip is used to combine two dictionary items into a one

```
 mylist=list(zip(dict1,dict2))
```